# How to align equations like this?

Tags: equations, align

[image: image align]

So I want to align this equation such that dx/dt all align in the same line as the picture given for reference.

```
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dy}=a(y-x)+u\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-xz+cy \\
\frac{dz}{dt}=xy-bz\\
\frac{du}{dt}=xz+du 
\end{matrix}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `aligned`, rather than `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  \frac{dx}{dy} &= a(y-x)+u \\
  \frac{dy}{dt} &= -xz+cy \\
  \frac{dz}{dt} &= xy-bz \\
  \frac{du}{dt} &= xz+du
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> I want to align this equation such that dx/dt all align in the same line

I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and use a `drcases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'drcases' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{drcases}
  \frac{dx}{dy}=a(y-x)+u \\
  \frac{dy}{dt}=-xz+cy   \\
  \frac{dz}{dt}=xy-bz    \\
  \frac{du}{dt}=xz+du 
\end{drcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of switching your code to a `drcases` environment.

Comment: I too like this method +1

Comment: @Mico You're always welcome. Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make some assumptions about document settings, but something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \left.
            \begin{matrix}
                \frac{dx}{dy} = &a(y-x)+u\\
                \frac{dy}{dt} = &-xz+cy \\
                \frac{dz}{dt} = &xy-bz\\
                \frac{du}{dt} = &xz+du 
            \end{matrix}
        \right\}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about aligning the equations in the middle of the page you could use the code below. (using the ams math package). (P.S. Use the ampersand character &, to set the points where the equations are vertically aligned.)

```
\begin{align*} 
   \frac{dx}{dy} &=a(y-x)+u\\
   \frac{dy}{dt} &=-xz+cy \\
   \frac{dz}{dt} &=xy-bz\\
   \frac{du}{dt} &=xz+du
\end{align*}
```

Here's the result you will get:

[image]

Comment: Judging by the OP's code, it would appear to be desirable to be able to assign a single equation number to the four-line expression. How might your code be adapted to permit achievning this objective?

Comment: If that's the desirable result, then @egreg 's got correct answer. So we could wrap the code in the align envinormnet, with  an equation environment and \left \right\}.